# Jmeter loop controller data from php array or html response

Tags: php, jmeter

My idea is to create dynamic php array with url's in it and then send it to jmeter. How can I take this array to be url dataprovider and iterate over it? Is it done somehow with user defined variables? That would be awesome.

Thanks

Edit:
If the first idea is not possible, is it possible to read the URL's from http response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with XML http response and xPath Extractor Sampler. Then used ForEach Controller with the data got from XML response. Was the best way to do that I think.

Comment: Completely acceptable solution. As well you can accept your own answer to complete this question.